# Calculadora JavaScript 3

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Problema a la hora de hacer las operaciones con decimales, siempre dara enteros.

```js
//Variables
  
  var a;
  var b;
  var c;
  var d;
  var f;

  var operandoa;
  var operandob;
  var operacion;

  var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
  var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
  var division = document.getElementById("division");
  var multiplicacion = document.getElementById("multiplicacion");
  var resta = document.getElementById("resta");
  var suma = document.getElementById("suma");
  var verificar = document.getElementById("verificar");
  var uno = document.getElementById("uno");
  var dos = document.getElementById("dos");
  var tres = document.getElementById("tres");
  var cuatro = document.getElementById("cuatro");
  var cinco = document.getElementById("cinco");
  var seis = document.getElementById("seis");
  var siete = document.getElementById("siete");
  var ocho = document.getElementById("ocho");
  var nueve = document.getElementById("nueve");
  var cero = document.getElementById("cero");
  var coma = document.getElementById("coma");

//Eventos


function init() {
  uno.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "1";
  }
  dos.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "2";
  }
  tres.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "3";
  }
  cuatro.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "4";
  }
  cinco.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "5";
  }  
  seis.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "6";
  }
  siete.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "7";
  }
  ocho.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "8";
  }  
  nueve.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "9";
  }
  cero.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "0";
  }
  coma.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + ",";
  }
  
  //--------------------------------------------------
  //Resetear
  //--------------------------------------------------
  
  reset.onclick = function(e){
    resetear();
  }
  
  //--------------------------------------------------
  // Operaciones
  //--------------------------------------------------
  
  suma.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "+";
    limpiar1(a);
  }
  resta.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "-";
    limpiar2(b);
  }
  multiplicacion.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "*";
    limpiar3(c);
  }
  division.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "/";
    limpiar4(d);
  }
  verificar.onclick = function(e){
    operandob = resultado.textContent.substr(operandoa.length + 1);
    resolver();
  }
}

function limpiar1(a){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "+";
}
function limpiar2(b){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "-";
}
function limpiar3(c){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "*";
}
function limpiar4(d){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "/";
}

//------------------------------------------------

function resetear(){
  resultado.textContent = "";
  operandob = 0;
  operandob = 0;
  operacion = "";
}
  
//------------------------------------------------

function resolver(){
  
  var res = "";
  
  switch(operacion){
    case "+":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) + parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
    case "-":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) - parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
      case "*":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) * parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
      case "/":
      
      if (operandob == 0){
        res = 0;
        window.alert("ERROR");
      } else {
        res = parseFloat(operandoa) / parseFloat(operandob);
      }
      break;
  }
  resetear();
  resultado.textContent = res;
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
 font-size:22px;
}
li{
 list-style:none;
}
html {
 height: 100%;
 background: white;
 background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 24%, #CCE);
 background-size: cover;
}
#Contenedor{
 width: 290px;
 text-align: center;
 height:auto;
 margin:4px auto;
}
#calculadora{
 width: 234px;
 height: 230px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:2px;
 background-color: #65D277;
}
#resultado{
 margin:8px auto;
 width:95%;
 height:30px;
 font-size: 16px;
 overflow:hidden;
 text-align: right;
 color:#48484D;
 padding: 4px;
 background-color:#fff;
 box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 4px 1px #eee;
}
.Teclas li{
 width:50px;
 height:30px;
 border-radius:3px;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#6C73FA;
 cursor:pointer;
 float:left;
 margin: 0px -3px 5px 8px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px 0px #444651;
}
.Teclas li:hover{
 background-color: #BEF9F0;
 color: #6C73FA;
 transition:0.2s;
}
.Teclas li:active{
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #444651;
}
.verificar{
 width: 93.4% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Tarea 2.8 - Kepriel</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
 <div id="Contenedor">
  <header class="Titulo">
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>
  </header>
  <section id="calculadora">
   <header class="top">
    <div id="resultado"></div>
   </header>
   <ul class="Teclas">
        <li></li>
        <li>DEL</li>
        <li id="reset" onclick="init()">C</li>
        <li></li>
    <li id="siete" onclick="init()">7</li>
    <li id="ocho" onclick="init()">8</li>
    <li id="nueve" onclick="init()">9</li>
    <li id="division"onclick="init()">&frasl;</li>
    <li id="cuatro" onclick="init()">4</li>
    <li id="cinco" onclick="init()">5</li>
    <li id="seis" onclick="init()">6</li>
    <li id="multiplicacion" onclick="init()">*</li>
    <li id="uno" onclick="init()">1</li>
    <li id="dos" onclick="init()">2</li>
    <li id="tres" onclick="init()">3</li>
    <li id="resta" onclick="init()">-</li>
    <li id="cero" onclick="init()">0</li>
    <li id="coma" onclick="init()">.</li>
    <li id="suma" onclick="init()">+</li>
    <li id="verificar" onclick="init()">=</li>
   </ul>
  </section>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculadora.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tienes un typo: `tectContent` !== `textContent `

Comment: Gracias pero despues lo hago y me da todo en entero no me lee los decimales

Comment: No te lee los decimales porque usas `parseInt`, no `parseFloat`

Comment: lo cambie ya a parseFloat pero aun asi no me los detecta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El fallo que tienes ahora mismo es la coma:

```js
let numero='89,3';
let numero2='89.3';

console.log(parseFloat(numero));

console.log(parseFloat(numero2));
```

Javascript usa la notación anglosajona y parseFloat lee caracteres hasta que encuentra uno que no se adapta a un número. Cuando encuentra la coma para de leer y transforma lo que haya encontrado hasta ese momento.

Por otro lado...

- estás ejecutando mucho código innecesario en cada click: el método init() sólo se debería ejecutar una vez.
- cuando tengas mucho código que es casi una repetición de lo mismo, seguramente puedas escribirlo mucho más brevemente, encontrando lo común y parametrizando el resto.

Mi propuesta:

```js
//Variables

let operandoa;
let operandob;
let operacion;

let numeros= [ 'cero', 'uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro', 'cinco', 'seis',
  'siete', 'ocho', 'nueve'];

let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

numeros.forEach(function (id, indice) {
  let tecla= document.getElementById(id);
  tecla.addEventListener('click', function() {
    resultado.textContent += indice;
  });
});


let reset = document.getElementById("reset");
let division = document.getElementById("division");
let multiplicacion = document.getElementById("multiplicacion");
let resta = document.getElementById("resta");
let suma = document.getElementById("suma");
let verificar = document.getElementById("verificar");
let coma = document.getElementById("coma");
let borradoParcial = document.getElementById("borradoParcial");

//Eventos

coma.onclick = function(e){
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + ',';
}

//--------------------------------------------------
//Resetear
//--------------------------------------------------

function resetear () {
  resultado.textContent = '';
  operandob = 0;
  operandob = 0;
  operacion = '';
}
reset.addEventListener('click',resetear );

function del() {
  resultado.textContent=resultado.textContent.substring(0,resultado.textContent.length-1);
}
borradoParcial.addEventListener('click',del );

//--------------------------------------------------
// Operaciones
//--------------------------------------------------

//esta función devuelve una función que añade el operador dado
function generador(operador) {
  return function() {
    operandoa = resultado.textContent.replace(',','.');
    operacion = operador;
    resultado.textContent +=operador;
  };
}

suma.addEventListener('click', generador('+'))
resta.addEventListener('click', generador('-'));
multiplicacion.addEventListener('click', generador('*'));
division.addEventListener('click', generador('/'));

verificar.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  operandob = resultado.textContent.substr(operandoa.length + 1);
  resolver();
});


//------------------------------------------------


  
//------------------------------------------------

function resolver(){
  
  var res = '';
  
  switch(operacion){
    case "+":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) + parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
    case "-":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) - parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
      case "*":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) * parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
      case "/":
      
      if (operandob == 0){
        res = 0;
        window.alert("ERROR");
      } else {
        res = parseFloat(operandoa) / parseFloat(operandob);
      }
      break;
  }
  resetear();
  resultado.textContent = res.toString().replace('.',',');
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
 font-size:22px;
}
li{
 list-style:none;
}
html {
 height: 100%;
 background: white;
 background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 24%, #CCE);
 background-size: cover;
}
#Contenedor{
 width: 290px;
 text-align: center;
 height:auto;
 margin:4px auto;
}
#calculadora{
 width: 234px;
 height: 230px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:2px;
 background-color: #65D277;
}
#resultado{
 margin:8px auto;
 width:95%;
 height:30px;
 font-size: 16px;
 overflow:hidden;
 text-align: right;
 color:#48484D;
 padding: 4px;
 background-color:#fff;
 box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 4px 1px #eee;
}
.Teclas li{
 width:50px;
 height:30px;
 border-radius:3px;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#6C73FA;
 cursor:pointer;
 float:left;
 margin: 0px -3px 5px 8px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px 0px #444651;
}
.Teclas li:hover{
 background-color: #BEF9F0;
 color: #6C73FA;
 transition:0.2s;
}
.Teclas li:active{
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #444651;
}
.verificar{
 width: 93.4% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="Contenedor">
  <header class="Titulo">
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>
  </header>
  <section id="calculadora">
    <header class="top">
      <div id="resultado"></div>
    </header>
    <ul class="Teclas">
      <li></li>
      <li id="borradoParcial">DEL</li>
      <li id="reset">C</li>
      <li></li>
      <li id="siete">7</li>
      <li id="ocho">8</li>
      <li id="nueve">9</li>
      <li id="division">&frasl;</li>
      <li id="cuatro">4</li>
      <li id="cinco">5</li>
      <li id="seis" >6</li>
      <li id="multiplicacion">*</li>
      <li id="uno" >1</li>
      <li id="dos" >2</li>
      <li id="tres">3</li>
      <li id="resta">-</li>
      <li id="cero">0</li>
      <li id="coma">.</li>
      <li id="suma">+</li>
      <li id="verificar">=</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda me sirvio de mucha ayuda

Comment: Como te comenté, aquí tienes algunas cosas que puedes hacer para mejorar el código, eliminando muchas repeticiones. Si tienes cualquier duda comenta aquí o en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com), cuando puedas entrar.

Comment: Bonus: Te he añadido cómo borrar